# How to omit some xticks in a barplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

If I run the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict({"1":5, "3":7, "8":29, "11":12, "30":7, "50":3, "100":34})

plt.bar(d.keys(), d.values())
plt.show()
```

I will get this output:

[image]

But how can I omit some of the xticks so the plot looks like this:

[image]

In my application I have an ordered dictionary with thousands of keys and the x-axis gets really messy even if I rotate the labels or decrease their fontsize. I'm not interested in every single bar, but how they are distributed over the x-axis, then showing the median and some others quantiles of the dictionary keys are enough. The histogram doesn't seem to be a good solution since it puts the 100 quite far away from the other keys, in the example I gave, and I want all of them to be next to each other. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `plt.xticks([0, 2, 6])` would produce your sample plot. Without some sort of pattern for the ticks you want to keep, it's hard to help further.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.